# Como retornar um bloco JSON via requisição

Tags: javascript, json

Recebi um desafio que tenho que realizar meu curriculum no HTML, so que minhas experiencias profissionais e  habilidades tecnicas tenho que pegar via requisição como descrito abaixo:

"A lista de empresas DEVE ser carregada através de uma requisição que deve retornar o mockup de um JSON contendo a lista de empresas que por sua vez deve ser interpretada e disposta na tela corretamente (Você pode utilizar o site https://www.mockable.io/ para criar o mockup)."

Seguindo a orientação fiz meus json GET no mockable.io e ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
{
"empresas": [
{
    "id": "1",
 "periodo": "[2012-2015]",
 "empresa": "OLISA COM. DE FRIOS E LATICINIOS LTDA",
 "cargo": "AUXILIAR ADMINISTRATIVO",
 "funcoes": "ROTINAS ADMINISTRATIVAS, TELEVENDAS, COMPRAS."
},
{
    "id": "2",
 "periodo": "[2015-2016]",
 "empresa": "OLISA COM. DE FRIOS E LATICINIOS LTDA",
 "cargo": "VENDEDOR",
 "funcoes": "VENDA DE FRIOS E LATICINIOS, ESTOQUE, LOGISTICA."
},
{
    "id": "3",
 "periodo": "[2016-2018]",
 "empresa": "E.C.P NUNES DE OLIVEIRA COM. DE FRIOS E LATICINIOS ME",
 "cargo": "VENDEDOR",
 "funcoes": "VENDA DE FRIOS E LATICINIOS, ESTOQUE, LOGISTICA."
},
{
    "id": "4",
 "periodo": "[2018-ATUAL]",
 "empresa": "ASTERSOFT SISTEMAS LTDA",
 "cargo": "VENDEDOR",
 "funcoes": "VENDA E COMERCIO DE SOFTWARE ERP/CONTABIL/LOTEAMENTO."
}
]
}
```

e meu HTML ficou assim:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Curriculum Samuel de Oliveira Neto</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    "use strict";
    const urlXP = "https://demo1915525.mockable.io/expprofissional";
    const urlHAB = "https://demo1915525.mockable.io/habtecnicas";

    function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
      let xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
          callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
      }
      xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

    httpGetAsync(urlXP, (resp) => {
      console.log("urlXP", resp);
    })

    httpGetAsync(urlHAB, (resp) => {
      console.log("urlHAB", resp);

    })
  </script>

  <h1> Samuel de Oliveira Neto </h1>
  <hr>
  <h3>Brasileiro, União estavel, 23 anos.</h3>
  <h3>Rua José Roque Salton, 1334 - Terra Bonita - Londrina-PR</h3>
  <h3>Categoria CNH: A/B</h3>
  <h3>Telefone: (43)99687-5004 / E-mail: samudemolay27@gmail.com</h3>
  <hr>

  <h1>Experiências Profissionais:</h1>

  <hr>
  <hr>
  <h1> Formação: </h1>
  <hr>
  <h3>•Ensino Médio Completo. </h3>
  <h3>•Cursando Analise e Desenvolvimento de Sistemas (Faculdade Positivo Londrina) Periodo: 4º Semestre (2º Ano) </h3>
  <hr>

  <h1>Habilidades Técnicas:</h1>
  <hr>
  <hr>

  <h1>Idiomas:</h1>
  <hr>
  <h3>•Inglês: Escrita - Básico / Leitura - Básico</h3>
  <hr>

  <h1>Interesses Profissionais:</h1>
  <hr>
  <h3>•Desenvolvimento Front-End</h3>
  <h3>•Disponibilidade de horarios: matutino e vespertino</h3>
</body>

</html>
```

A Pergunta é: como fazer para aparecer as informaçoes do meu json dentro dos respectivos campos HTML? (Exp. Profissional e Habilidades Tecnicas?)

Att.

Comment: de que forma tu vai ter acesso a esse json?no teu html tu tem acesso?

Answer (score 1):

Existem diversas formas de escrever isso. Em todas você vai precisar de uma função javascript para percorrer o array de empresas que retornou na requisição.

Uma delas é coloque um div com um id ou class que encapsule o `<h1>` das empresas. Na sua função passe como parâmetro o retorno desse GET,
para manipular ele usando um forEach, selecione a div criada com um querySelector, e dentro do forEach, crie dinamicamente os elementos de acordo com o que você precisa. O ideal é que seu HTML esteja melhor formatado, com tags especificas para cada seção.

Ex:

```
function criarElementos (data){
  var empresas = document.querySelector('.empresas');

  data.empresas.forEach(function(empresa){
     var novoElemento = document.createElement('span');
     novoElemento.innerText = empresa.id;
  })
};
```

Leia esses documentos, continue estudando sempre e boa sorte!

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 0):

Tendo os valores em uma variável `resp` basta acessar as propriedades desejadas para pegar os valores e usar o `innerText` para setar em um elemento:

```js
//Exemplo de dados 
respHT = [{
  html: "HTML Básico",
  node: "Node Básico"
}];

respEP = [{
  id: "1",
  periodo: "[2012-2015]",
  empresa: "OLISA COM. DE FRIOS E LATICINIOS LTDA",
  cargo: "AUXILIAR ADMINISTRATIVO",
  funcoes: "ROTINAS ADMINISTRATIVAS, TELEVENDAS, COMPRAS."
}];

//Faz um loop no array de resposta e adiciona ao elemento
for (ht in respHT[0]) document.getElementById('ht').innerHTML += '<li>' + respHT[0][ht] + '</li>';

for (ep of respEP) document.getElementById('ep').innerHTML += '<li>' + ep.empresa + ' - ' + ep.cargo + '</li>';
```

```html
<ul id="ht"></ul>
<ul id="ep"></ul>
```